# how to update the data using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can see the updated data when I refreshed the page.when I use the $state.reload it is working fine..So how to solve this without using $tate.reload how can I update data when I click on save button.
Here is my javascript code:

```
 vm.myFuncUpdate= function () {
    if (!vm.id) { vm.id= vm.infoFunc.date; }
    if (!vm.pid) { vm.pid= vm.infoFunc.person}

    mySrvc.myPostData(id,pid,function (response, status) {
       console.log(response);
        vmCancel();

    });

}
```

Html code:

```
   <input type="button" value="Save" ng-
   click="myFuncUpdate()" />
```

Service:

```
 this.myPostData= function (id, pid, funCallBack) {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://myapp/api/profile/details",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'dataType': 'json'
        },
        data: { id: id, pid: pid }
    }).success(function (response, status) {
        funCallBack(response, status);

    }).error(function (reason, status) {
        if (status == 400)
            alert(JSON.stringify(reason));
        else if (status == 404)
            alert("Something wrong!");
        else
            alert("Something Wrong");

    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's really not clear what you are asking. "I have to update the data when I clicked on save button.But the problem is,the data is updated but I can see the updated data when I refresh the page.".  Does this mean you **want** to see the update or you **don't**?

Comment: I can see the updated only after refreshing the page,for this I Used $state.reload.Is there is any possible way instead of $state.reload(); @Claies

Comment: well, it *sounds like* you need to update the client side data in the `.success` function.  as a side note, you shouldn't use `.success`, it's been deprecated, and removed from newer angular releases.

Comment: how can i solve this?please help me @Claies

Comment: what is `funCallback` doing?  it should be updating the view.

Comment: @no it is not updating the view.it is a call back function

Comment: yes, but it **should be** updating the view, that's the entire point of the callback function.

Comment: @Claies ok.So how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $scope.formName.$setPristine();

I recommend checking out the form validation section in AngularJS as it will give you a good starting point and understanding of how this works.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have an Api call which will fetch and show that updated data right ?
so you just need to call that again when you use this api "http://myapp/api/profile/details

```
   var init = function(){
        APIServices.profileData.success(function(data) {
        self.newProfileData = data;
        //console.log(self.newProfileData);
    })    
    } init();
$rootScope.$on('update-Data', function(){
        init();
    });

this.myPostData= function (id, pid, funCallBack) {
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://myapp/api/profile/details",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'dataType': 'json'
    },
    data: { id: id, pid: pid }
}).success(function (response, status) {
    funCallBack(response, status);
     **$rootScope.$broadcast('update-Data');**

}).error(function (reason, status) {
    if (status == 400)
        alert(JSON.stringify(reason));
    else if (status == 404)
        alert("Something wrong!");
    else
        alert("Something Wrong");

});
```

}

this is one of the way to update a template , ps:i assume u have a fetch api if not then i think you can use $watch to watch over the model

Comment: sorry I can't get you where I have to call the init(); function

Comment: do you have an fetch api ? which will fetch ur updated profile data ?

Comment: now check i have updated the code . u just need to call ur update api into that init. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139827/mean-stack .. i am online now if u need help